# Using Mutate to rank specific columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a relative newbie to `dplyr`.  I have a `data.frame` organized with each store name and source (made up of the results for 2018) making up the observations.  The variables are total revenue, quantity, customer experience score, and a few others.

I'd like to rank each category in the `data.frame` and create new observations.  All variables would be ranked in descending order, but customer experience and one additional column would be ranked in ascending order.  The source I'd like to call this would be called "ranks".

```
store <- c("NYC", "Chicago", "Boston")
source <- c("2018", "2018", "2018")
revenue <- c(10000, 50000, 2000)
quantity <- c(100, 50, 20)
satisfaction <- c(3, 2, 5)
table <- cbind(store, source, revenue, quantity, satisfaction)
```

I was able to get what I needed using mutate, but I had to manually name each new column.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way to rank these values out there!

Here is what I originally did:

```
table <- table %>%
mutate(revenue_rank = rank(-revenue), quantity_rank = rank(-quantity), satisfaction_rank = rank(satisfaction))
```

Comment: What you have tried? Also, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: By "rank", do you mean sort?

Comment: I was able to use the following code, but it would create additional columns instead of doing the rank within each category in the given row.

Comment: Please provide your expected output

Comment: Expected output would create an additional row for each store name, with the source column showing "rank".  Each variable would have the result of the rank code listed above.  If it isn't achievable this way, is there an easier way to use mutate_all that would create additional columns for the ranks, where each column is named based on the column name with "_rank" after it, where all columns are ranked in descending order with the exception of customer experience?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you're having to do something repeatedly in a data frame, such as calculating ranks, you probably want to reshape to long data. Also note that what you got from `cbind` is a matrix, not data frame--probably not what you want, since this means numeric variables actually come through as characters. Instead of `cbind`, use `data.frame` or `data_frame` (for a tibble).

What I did here is gathered into a long data frame, grouped by the measures (revenue, quantity, or satisfaction), then gave ranks based on the value, keeping in mind that you wanted different orders for satisfaction and the other measures.

```r
library(tidyverse)

store <- c("NYC", "Chicago", "Boston")
source <- c("2018", "2018", "2018")
revenue <- c(10000, 50000, 2000)
quantity <- c(100, 50, 20)
satisfaction <- c(3, 2, 5)

df <- data_frame(store, source, revenue, quantity, satisfaction)

df %>%
    gather(key = measure, value = value, revenue:satisfaction) %>%
    group_by(measure) %>%
    mutate(rank = ifelse(measure == "satisfaction", rank(value), rank(-value))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-value) %>%
    mutate(measure = paste(measure, "rank", sep = "_")) %>%
    spread(key = measure, value = rank)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   store   source quantity_rank revenue_rank satisfaction_rank
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1 Boston  2018               3            3                 3
#> 2 Chicago 2018               2            1                 1
#> 3 NYC     2018               1            2                 2
```

Created on 2018-05-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks!  Is it possible to do the way I wanted it done?  The only solution I can think of is to use mutate, select only the rank column results, and bind the results to the original data frame.

Comment: I'm not totally understanding how this is different from what you want aside from being long instead of wide

Comment: How would I go about making it wide with the following caveats:  all columns are named with the column name _rank, and the rank according to my ascending and descending preferences?

Comment: I'll amend my answer

Comment: Thanks Camile this works perfectly.  How would I amend the ifelse statement if I had a 2nd variable in addition to satisfaction perhaps called cleanliness that I wanted to rank in ascending order?

Comment: Change `measure == "satisfaction"` to `measure %in% c("satisfaction", "cleanliness")`, or if that starts to become too unwieldy, add a column to designate which measures are ascending and which are descending